# Cannot kill process in Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, process

I'm running Windows 7 x64. Once in a while I have a process that freezes and that cannot be killed. I've tries the following:

1. Process Explorer
2. pskill
3. taskkill /F /T

Nothing worked. Tools report that the process was killed successfully, but it just stays there.

How do I kill it?

**UPDATE**

I know now that it always happen when some application tries to connect to a SQL Server and the SQL Server is not started. The application always freezes.

**UPDATE**

As **DougN** assumed the number of handles of the frozen process was indeed 1. In the process explorer it showed this

Desktop \Default

Not sure what this is. I couldn't close this handle from Process Explorer. Then I searched for other processes that contained references to the frozen process. Found two handles in csrss.exe. Closed them. Then I tried to close the frozen process again, but it didn't work.

**UPDATE**
I have tried the application called Advanced Process Termination v4.2. Which has 12+2+2 methods to kill stubborn processes. I've tried all the 16 methods and non of them worked. I believe that this is a Windows 7 bug.

**UPDATE**
Seems that [here's](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproperf/thread/598fe2b4-844d-412d-b195-5fa53dc62661) the discussion of this problem:

Answer (score 1):

Look in Task Manager and add a column for Handles.  If it has a very low number of handles (less than 10?  Often 1) the process is dead and not running, but can't unload because something has a handle to it.

When it's happened to me, I had to find the process that launched it, and close the parent.  Perhaps you could use Procexplorer and find the handle and manually release it though?

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that, but it's unlikely the reason, because last time the application was launched from Visual Studio and I closed it, but couldn't close the child process.

Comment: In that case, also try killing mspdbsrv.exe (not sure if that will help, but seems related).

Comment: I have updated my question. Also I couldn't find mspdbsrv.exe in the process list

Answer (score 0):

I guess rebooting is not an option... If the process blocks the file access, you may try a tool like [Unlocker](http://ccollomb.free.fr/unlocker/) which can release the lock of a file in most cases (and also killing the process). Maybe you could provide more information about the process which hangs. Maybe another guy already had the same problem.

Comment: I can close files from Proces Explorer also. Which I did. But this doesn't help.

Comment: This happens to different processes. This time the process is a GUI application which uses SQL server. Nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

The only time a process can't be killed is when it is stuck in system/kernel call. Your comment that it happens to different processes suggest either hardware or driver problem.

Check disk for SMART errors, do a SMART test (using [smartmontools](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki)), possibly a surface scan (using [MHDD](http://hddguru.com/software/2005.10.02-MHDD/) or [HDTune](http://www.hdtune.com)).
Do a memory check (using [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/)). Inspect system logs for errors/warnings.